# Trouble with 'for loop' for Fibonacci sequence

Tags: for-loop, fibonacci

I recently started programming and currently working on a method for Fibonacci Sequence and it seems the method only adds 0s after the first two number. I think there is an issue with my for loop but can't get my head around it.

```
static int fib(int number)
        {
            if (number == 1 || number == 2)
                return 1;

            int[] fibBase = new int[number];
            fibBase[0] = 1;
            fibBase[1] = 1;

            for (int i = 2; i < fibBase.Length; i++)
            {
            
                int temp = fibBase[i - 2] + fibBase[i - 1];

                fibBase[i] = temp;

                int lastindex = fibBase.Length;
                number = fibBase[lastindex - 1];

            }
            
            foreach (int fib in fibBase)
                Console.WriteLine(fib);
            return number;
            
                
        }
```

Comment: Based on the capitalisation of `Length` and the `foreach` syntax I'm almost certain this is c# not java @StephanBranczyk

Comment: Ah! Ok! Forget what I said then.

Comment: Regardless of the questionable parts - this function does seems to print a fibonacci sequence (when called with a parameter greater than 2) - what specifically is your issue? How are you using this? What is happening? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Hi Stephan, yes this is C#! I just double checked my code and it seems to be working for some reason. Sorry for the trouble everyone.

Comment: @KPark for future questions, you can include a tag to indicate the language so that people unambiguously know what language your question is written in.